# Is my SQL function returning the correct result or just the first entry in the column?

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm working on a website and I'm trying to check a users level and display the result. The function I have selects user_lvl from a database and returns the result (user_lvl is an int). I then have a variable that is equal to this function when a user logs in. The session variable for the user is then set to this. The problem I'm having is that when I echo the data for the user, it's not the correct result. I'm pretty sure it's selecting the first entry in the database rather than the current user who is logged in. I know it's probably something simple I'm missing, but how do I get the result I want?

Here's the code :

```
// here is the function to get the user level from the databse 
function getUserLvl() {
    global $conn;

    $sql = "SELECT user_lvl FROM users";
    $Lvl = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    $getUserLvl = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Lvl);

    return $getUserLvl;
}
```

And here is the login script, I've added all of it just so it's easier to understand but the main parts involved will be separated at the top.

```
$userLvl = getUserLvl();

session_start();
$_SESSION['userLvl'] = $userLvl;

<h3 class="ui center aligned header">User Level: <?php echo implode(',', $_SESSION['userLvl']) ?></h3>
```

---

```
<?php
require_once 'publicFunction.php'; // load functions script to access user variables e.g getUserLvl

    if (isset($_POST['login-submit'])) {

        require 'config.php';

        $userMail = $_POST['user'];
        $pass = $_POST['password'];
        $userLvl = getUserLvl();

        if (empty($userMail) || empty($pass)) {
            header("Location: ../index.php?error=emptyFields");
            exit();
        } else {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? OR email=?";
            $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

            if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                header("Location: ../index.php?error=sqlError");
                exit();
            } else {
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $userMail, $userMail);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

                if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $passCheck = password_verify($pass, $row['password']);

                    if ($passCheck == false) {
                        header("Location: ../index.php?error=invalidPassword");
                        exit();
                    } else if ($passCheck == true) {
                        session_start();
                        $_SESSION['userId'] = $row['userID'];
                        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
                        $_SESSION['userLvl'] = $userLvl;

                        header("Location: ../index.php?login=Success");
                        exit();
                    } else {
                        header("Location: ../index.php?error=invalidPassword");
                        exit();
                    }
                } else {
                    header("Location: ../index.php?error=invalidUsername");
                    exit();
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        header("Location: ../index.php");
        exit();
    }
```

Comment: There is no where condition in your SQL statement.

Comment: When I add a WHERE condition to the function it causes it to not echo the value properly. Just displays 'User Level:   " instead of "User Level: 1".

Comment: @McFlurry You can’t call userlvl from function before login in and pass userID to function! So, Change function to this `function getUserLvl($userID) {
    global $conn;
$sql = "SELECT user_lvl FROM users WHERE user_id = " . $userID;` and then call function like this just above sessions `$userLvl = getUserLvl($row['userID']);` and pass session like this `$_SESSION['userLvl'] = $userLvl['userLvl']`

Comment: Thank you so much! You've just helped me fix a couple problems with that answer. :D

Comment: :) nice to hear that

Answer (score 0):

Your current SQL statement does not have any `where` condition to specify the correct user. Assuming you have a column for user IDs (let's call it `user_id`), you should adjust your query to look like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT user_lvl FROM users WHERE user_id = " . $userID;
```

Where `$userID` is the ID of the current user.

Comment: Where would I declare the $userID variable? inside the function or out of it?

Comment: As @Dlk mentioned in a comment, consider passing the user ID as a parameter to `getUserLvl()`. Or whichever way you see fit :)